# How connect to host via soap in PHP?

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to implement an experian bank account checking facility on the systems at work.

I'm trying to do this using php and Soap.

This is my first time using Soap so I'm not entirely sure if i'm doing it correct.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
    $options = array(
        'local_cert'=>'certificate.p12', 
        'passphrase'=>'mypass', 
        'location'=>"https://secure.authenticator.uat.uk.experian.com/WASPAuthenticator/Service.asmx",
        'uri'=>'http://www.uk.experian.com/WASP/',
    );

    $authenticationBlock = "<WASPAuthenticationRequest>";
    $authenticationBlock .= "<ApplicationName>YFR Admin</ApplicationName>";
    $authenticationBlock .= "<AuthenticationLevel>CertificateAuthentication</AuthenticationLevel>";
    $authenticationBlock .= "<AuthenticationParameters/>";
    $authenticationBlock .= "</WASPAuthenticationRequest>";

    try {
        $client = new SoapClient(null, $options);

        $result = $client->STS($authenticationBlock);  // experian function - possibly the problem line

    } catch (soapFault $fault) {
        trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
    } 

    var_dump($result);

?>
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Fatal error: SOAP Fault: (faultcode: HTTP, faultstring: Could not connect to host) in /myfile/ on line 21

I feel I'm using the right details in the right places but figured I must be missing something obvious or just doing the whole thing wrong :)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you connect using SOAP UI or a similar tool?

Comment: no i can't even with SOAP  UI

Answer (score 0):

Your `'location'=>"https://secure.authenticator.uat.uk.experian.com/WASPAuthenticator/Service.asmx",`  is not reachable. Are you sure of this value? This is what the SoapClient is telling you.